# Can't select GDB in Qt Creator on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, gdb, qt-creator

I've selected GDB instead of CDB as the debugger in Qt Creator on Windows:

[image]

But when I start debugging a program, it fails with this error:

```
Unable to create a debugger engine of the type "No engine"
```

It works if I select CDB from the Combo. Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it? I assume I do have GDB installed if it's in the combo box, right?

**Edit:** I see where the problem might lie, but still no idea how do I fix it:

[image]

[Open the above image in a new tab to see in full resolution.] It says "Not recognized" for GDB.

**Edit 2:** I just remembered that I'm using the MSVC compiler, and the Qt libs are compiled for MSVC:

[image]

Maybe that's the reason? Although GDB should be able to debug any executable, not just ones generated by gcc, so I'm not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: Don't assume; check! :-) Is MinGW installed? (Usually in `C:\mingw...` or `C:\Program Files\mingw...`). In general, you use the debugger that matches your compiler -- are you compiling with MinGW?

Comment: @Cameron I just made an edit, gdb.exe is indeed there at `c:\QtCreator\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\gdb.exe`, but Qt Creator says "Not recognized" under "Type" column, see the screenshot in my edit.

Comment: @Cameron And another thing - I'm using the MSVC kits, there's another edit.

Comment: `gdb` certainly can't debug just any program -- it needs the debug symbols in DWARF (or stab) format. MSVC's compiler only produces PDBs. Stick with `cdb` if you're using the MSVC toolchain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use GDB with MSVC-compiled code. It seems you're mixing the two.

CDB goes with Visual C++. GDB goes with MinGW(-w64).

Comment: Just to clarify - is this just the Qt Creator integration that's not working? I mean that gdb should be able to debug any executable in theory, right? Not just the ones compiled with gcc I mean.

Comment: @sashoalm: Theoretically yes, but you won't get very far without any debug symbols. See my comment on the question.